# My Flutter Project doesn't run on Emulator and it says "Could not find a command named "-"."

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, mobile-application

Source Code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Text('Hello There!'),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

When I run my test Flutter project (Source code is on the Top) on Android Studio it gives me the below error.(Flutter 3.7.0, Dart 2.19)

```
Could not find a command named "-".

Usage: dart <command|dart-file> [arguments]

Global options:
-h, --help                 Print this usage information.
-v, --verbose              Show additional command output.
    --version              Print the Dart SDK version.
    --enable-analytics     Enable analytics.
    --disable-analytics    Disable analytics.

Available commands:
  analyze    Analyze Dart code in a directory.
  compile    Compile Dart to various formats.
  create     Create a new Dart project.
  devtools   Open DevTools (optionally connecting to an existing application).
  doc        Generate API documentation for Dart projects.
  fix        Apply automated fixes to Dart source code.
  format     Idiomatically format Dart source code.
  info       Show diagnostic information about the installed tooling.
  migrate    Perform null safety migration on a project.
  pub        Work with packages.
  run        Run a Dart program.
  test       Run tests for a project.

Run "dart help <command>" for more information about a command.
See https://dart.dev/tools/dart-tool for detailed documentation.
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 64
```

I tried restarting my device and running `flutter doctor` but any of those didn't work.